# How do I reach the CloudWatch Logs Config page?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How do I access the CloudWatch logs config page, as described in this documentation, under the heading "Streaming CloudWatch Logs"?: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.html

[Screenshot of documentation for CloudWatch Logs Config in EBS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k8p5.png)

I looked under all of the config options for my Elastic Beanstalk image bug couldn't find this config page. This is after I followed the steps under the "Granting IAM Permissions for the CloudWatch Logs Agent" heading.